# A function that changes the dimension of a random vector make the random vector discrete?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, multivariate-analysis

One of my problems ask the question

Let $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector, and $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ be measurable. Then show that $g(\vec{x})$ is a discrete random vector.

I'm failing to see how the function $g$ makes the random vector discrete.

Comment: Is this the entire question? As is it seems clearly incorrect to me; e.g. say $x \sim \mathcal N(0,I)$ with $n = k$ and $g$ the identity, or $k=1$ and $g$ the first component.

Comment: This is what I suspected. I think that it may hold when $\vec{x}$ is discrete.